# Google Pixel devices: Soft keyboard hide button Vs Back press behaving differently after android 13

Tags: android, pixel, android-13

On updating Google pixel with android 13, I can see a change in behavior on back pressing vs dropp keyboard down button in my app. Essentially, 'onKeyPreIme' is not being called on hitting the hide keyboard button.

Is there any change there? How can I inject my code into the function which is called when we hit the 'hide keyboard'?

Hide keyboard button I'm talking about: [image]

Comment: found any solution on this?